# Change array values on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im trying to bulild some sort of table builder with jquery. (Display purposes 
only)

I have a button that adds a new row like this:

```
var row_id = 0;
var row_array = [];

row_array[0] = 0;

$('#add_row').click(function() {

    row_id ++;
    row_array.push(0);
    $('.rows_container').append('<li id="row_id_'+row_id+'" class="row"> <div class="control"><div class="add_columns">Pick number of columns +</div></div><ul class="column_container"> </ul></li>');
}
```

I start by setting the row_id to 0 and make an empty value in the array. So when i click the add row for the first time it will get an id of row_id_1 and create a index1 in the array witch is matching the current row id.

Now i have made a dialog/popup box thats shows when you click "Pick number of columns", and also its get the id og the row it is in with this function:

```
var parent_id = "";

$('body').on('click', '.add_columns', function() {
    $('.pick_columns').css('display', 'block');
    parent_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
}
```

In the popup i have an input field and a button, when you hit the button it is putting the number of columns you write in the field to the row

```
var min_columns = 1
var columns_used = 0;
var columns_left = 10 - columns_used;

$('.columns_ok').click(function() {
    var picked_value = parseInt($('.number_of_columns').val(),10);

    if((picked_value >= min_columns) && (picked_value <= columns_left)) {

        columns_id ++;

        $('#' + parent_id + ' .column_container').append('<li id="columns_id_' + parent_id + '_' + columns_id + '" class="column used_' + picked_value + '"></li>');

        columns_used += picked_value;
        columns_left = 10 - columns_used;

        $(this).parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
        $('.number_of_columns').val('');
        $('.error_message').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
        $('.error_message').css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

My questions is now: How do i save the columns_used value into the value of the array index that is the same number as the parent id?

So if you have selected 5 columns it adds to 5 to the value of the index1 in the array?

Comment: i advice you to try JqQrid Jquery plugin. Here is a link: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html . There is a lot of stuff already implemented there.

Comment: Thanks, but i really dont want a plugin for this :) im betting it is fairly simple, i just dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a property to Number objects. if you set them explicit with the new Operator.

there is a difference between

```
  x=5    this represents like in other programming language a primitive DataType, lets better say a primitive DataType object

  x=new Number (5)          this represents an object like =new Object ()

  x.valueOf ()  is representing the primitive DataType

  x.a="test";
```

but be carefull

```
   alert (5==5)   shows true

   alert (new Number(5)==new Number (5))  shows false, because the Number is threaded like an object, and compared if it is the same object
```

so you have to call

```
var x=new Number (5);
var y=new Number (5);
alert (x.valueOf()==y.valueOf());
```

in your case
     row_array[0] = new Number (0);

now you can add your property